# When I set a value of setRGB, getRGB returns a different value. Why?

Tags: java, rgb

Why here I setRGB () with three RGB colors (125, 126, 127), but when getRGB it returns another value that is (125, 126, 128).
For (122, 126, 127), it returns true (122, 126, 127).
Why?
And:
Input: image.setRGB (0, 0, 5072962) // 77 ----- 104 ----- 66 ------- 5072962
Output: 78 ------ 104 ------ 69 ------- 5138501
(With rgb = (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;)

My code:

//  77-------104-------66------5072962

```
final static int rgb = 5072962;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    //image.setRGB(0, 0, 5072962);
    Color c = new Color(125, 126, 127);
    image.setRGB(0, 0, c.getRGB());

    File outputFile = new File("123.jpg");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputFile);
        File f = new File("123.jpg");
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
        for (int h = 0; h < 1; h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < 1; w++) {
                int pixel = bi.getRGB(w, h);
                Color c2 = new Color(pixel);

                int red = c2.getRed();
                int green = c2.getGreen();
                int blue = c2.getBlue();

                int rgb = (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
                System.out.printf("%-8d%-8d%-8d%-8d", red, green, blue, rgb);
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error output File image!");
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear, but this `ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputFile);` followe by `File f = new File("123.jpg"); BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);` would suggest you're not reading the same file you saved/updated

Comment: thank you! I am doing a steganography, when I set the value, and then create a new image with the new value that I set. I want to output the image file, I will need to re-enter that file to get the value "text in image". I will definitely have to input the file containing the information inside to be able to extract the confidential information.

Comment: A very rough answer is that the internal format of a JPG doesn't give you precise control over the colour of each individual pixel.  It tends to smooth things out a bit.  So it's no surprise if the colour of a pixel in the JPG ends up slightly different from what you set it to.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, Yes, That's the problem, I've fixed it by switching to PNG. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, Did you Know about Image file formats ? I have the same problem before in similar case. I would like to suggest you the following.

When you use `jpg` for the image write operation to store in your storage, `RGB` values changes slightly because `jpg` format is a lossy compressed file format. This compression allows you for the optimal space to store the file but it doesn't store the information of `RGB` values you want.

So, If file format is not a big issue for you , then simply use `PNG` format. `PNG` format is a lossless compression file format so that you can retrieve `RGB` values you have set before in the program.

Hope it might help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not understand JPG well. Today I can present Steganography with my code. Thank you again!

Comment: congrats, glad to see it helped you